# Can't edit fields using textarea

Tags: php, html

when i click edit button on some other page the content to edit is visible in

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $data['Compliance']?>"/>
```

but the value to edit is not visible in

```
<textarea value="<?php echo $data['Compliance']?>"></textarea>
```

Can some one point out what's wrong i am doing here...Thanks in advance.`

In addition the Id of the field to edit is getting passed over to this page.

Comment: The value has to go between the tags, not as a value attribute.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

Comment: Textarea doesn't have a `value` attribute, put contents between the `<textarea></textarea>` tags

Comment: `<textarea><?php echo $data['Compliance']; ?></textarea>`

Comment: @Messy you need to get into the habit of accepting answers. This improves your reputation score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Textarea doesn't have a value attribute, put contents between the tags, like so:

```
<textarea>
  <?php echo $data['Compliance']?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: the closing semi-colon isn't needed. It's good practice but not required if there is a closing `?>` tag @Johannes edit: responded to a now deleted comment

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner *edit: responded to a now deleted comment*, then your comment is no longer needed and should've been deleted instead of edited.

Comment: @RacilHilan I'm keeping it for future users.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Fair enough, then your edit should've been converted to a note and removed the reference to Johannes. Now it is too late to do that, so you can delete it and add a new comment. However, perhaps it is better to add it as a note to the answer (i.e. enhance the answer). Comments are not essential part of SO and subject to deletion at anytime.

Comment: Thanks a bunch guys...@Funk Forty Niner,@aynber,@kerbholz....it worked